# Magento 1.x custom block with dynamic content

Tags: blocks, dynamic

Is it possible to add a block to Magento page which has dynamic content. 
Let's say I want to create a block in which a product is displayed. And after a certain period time 15 seconds for example the product changes and another one is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to create your phtml file then you include it in the page that you want, with xml or directly in a page code, then you customize it with js for exemple.

To include it:

1) You create the phtml file `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/homeproducts.phtml` then you add your custom code

2) to include it via **cms** page:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="home.product" template="catalog/product/homeproducts.phtml"}}
```

via **xml**:

*app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml*

```
<your_layout_handle> //where you want to display your block
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="home.product" template="catalog/product/homeproducts.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

3) Go to your phtml that you want to display this new block then add this:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('home.product'); ?>
```